# Read till specific pattern in a file- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with similar content as:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2294.68
cache size  : 460000 KB

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2296.68
cache size  : 460000 KB

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2294.68
cache size  : 460000 KB


processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2294.68
cache size  : 460080 KB
```

There might be multiple '\n' between each block and might be zero or more '\n' at the end also. My expected output is as:

```
{output: [{'processor': 0, 'cpu MHz': 2294.68, 'cache size': '460000 KB'},
{'processor': 1, 'cpu MHz': 2296.68, 'cache size': '460000 KB'},
{'processor': 2, 'cpu MHz': 2294.68, 'cache size': '460000 KB'},
{'processor': 3, 'cpu MHz': 2294.68, 'cache size': '460080 KB'}]}
```

I tried:

```
def read_cpu(file_: str):
    dct = {'output': []}
    with open(file_, 'r') as cpu_file:
        for line in cpu_file:
            if line.startswith('processor'):
                processor, processor_value = line.split(":")
            if line.startswith('cpu MHz'):
                mhz, mhz_value = line.split(":")
            if line.startswith("cache size"):
                cache, cache_size = line.split(":")

            if line=='\n':
                dct['output'].append(dict(processor=processor_value, mhz=mhz_value, cache=cache_size))
                continue
    return dct
```

It works based on new line character but, It doen't takes care of last block and the result is misleading if more that two \n at the end.

Comment: *I tried some approach but didn't get the perfect answer*, where are these approaches? The whole point of SO is for us to help you achieve that "perfect answer". If we can't see what you've already tried, how can we help you make it work?

Comment: @RoadRunner updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modification of Poster's code**

```
def read_cpu(file_: str):
    def get_values(line):
        " Utility function "
        k, v = line.split(':')
        return k.strip(), v.strip()

    dct = {'output': []}
    with open(file_, 'r') as cpu_file:

        processor = None

        for line in cpu_file:

            if line.startswith('processor'):
                processor, processor_value = get_values(line)
            if line.startswith('cpu MHz'):
                mhz, mhz_value = get_values(line)
            if line.startswith("cache size"):
                cache, cache_size = get_values(line)
            if line=='\n' and processor:
                dct['output'].append(dict(processor=processor_value, mhz=mhz_value, cache=cache_size))
                processor = None  # prevents outputting when multiple '\n'
                continue

        # last block
        if  processor:
            dct['output'].append(dict(processor=processor_value, mhz=mhz_value, cache=cache_size))
    return dct

print(read_cpu('system_info.txt'))
```

**Test File**

Include extra blank lines to show its still capable of processing

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2294.68
cache size  : 460000 KB

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2296.68
cache size  : 460000 KB




processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2294.68
cache size  : 460000 KB

ignored
ignored
processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 79
cpu MHz     : 2294.68
cache size  : 460080 KB


ignored
ignored
```

**Output**

```
{'output': [{'cache size': '460000 KB', 'cpu MHz': '2294.68', 'processor': '0'},
            {'cache size': '460000 KB', 'cpu MHz': '2296.68', 'processor': '1'},
            {'cache size': '460000 KB', 'cpu MHz': '2294.68', 'processor': '2'},
            {'cache size': '460080 KB', 'cpu MHz': '2294.68','processor': '3'}]}
```